# SQL - calculate average frequency along with other aggregations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a query for a table where each row is an order. This query should get the following numbers for every day of the week:

- [x] Total count of orders
- [x] Sum of total_amount
- [x] Total count of unique customers
- [ ] **Average order frequency of customers**

I can't find a way to get the last one (average order frequency). I have tried this below yet I get a `ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested`:

```
SELECT weekday,
    COUNT(*) AS orders,
    SUM(total_amount) AS revenue,
    COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS customers,
    AVG(COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)) AS avg_order_freq -- Average order frequency
FROM orders
GROUP BY weekday
```

I was hoping there was a single aggregate function for this. It would've been easier if I only had to get only the average order frequency, but I also had to aggregate other columns.

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: The average of a single observation is the single observation.  What is your formula for average order frequency?

Comment: @MikeOrganek If you group the orders table by customer_id and get the COUNT(customer_id), you get a list of how many times each customer_id shows up. Just get the average of this whole list and that's the average order frequency.

Comment: That average should be the same as `count(distinct customer_id) / count(*)`

Comment: @MikeOrganek Wow thanks, just realized I asked a dumb question. I completely overlooked that, didn't realize the solution is that simple. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do much dumber stuff, myself.  I would guess that you were too close to the solution you already had in mind, and that prevented you from seeing how adapt it for SQL.  Best of luck with your project!